# where do I download POIs from Wikipedia? placeopedia used to have them but is now gone

Tags: data, kml, convert, point-of-interest

I am trying to improve OpenStreetMap in Siem Reap, Cambodia.

A way I am doing this is to add temple locations. I hear that there is a dataset of temple locations available from Wikipedia (presumably amongst a broader dataset of POIs on Wikipedia).

How to extract these POIs from Wikipedia? Placeopedia used to have them, apparently, but now it's down.

One way I tried to do this was to download Wikipedia POIs in the Android app called OSMAND+. This, however, is in .OBF format.

Does anyone know how to convert from .OBF format to another one like .KML so I can view the file in JOSM and add missing temples?

Comment: http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/ is a new from MySociety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13761/where-is-wikipedias-coordinate-information-stored-and-how-can-i-retrieve-it) may help - it links to the Wikipedia [dump files](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProjekt_Georeferenzierung/Wikipedia-World/en).

If the temples have been geocoded you may be able to extract their coordinates by parsing the CSV files.

Good luck,
Steve

Answer (score 4):

There is a website which you can look into:  [www.motomapia.com](http://www.motomapia.com).

Here you can download POIs from wikipedia for a particular location.

All the POIs visible in the browser would be downloaded.

Regarding Obf , its a binary format and I dont think it can be converted to any other format.

Answer (score 3):

I was also trying to open obf file in GIS Software. But it is not possible to convert an obf file into kml or shape file. The obf format is a binary format used only for osmand.