# Getting CSV file of Wikipedia geolocations?

Tags: data, csv

Where do I get a CSV file containing (a reference to) all Wikipedia articles with lon/lat coordinates?

I am aware of [Retrieving Wikipedia's coordinate information?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13761/retrieving-wikipedias-coordinate-information) which refers to this page:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProjekt_Georeferenzierung/Hauptseite/Wikipedia-World/en

At one time that page offered a CSV download but it is no longer present, only the option to download a PostGIS data dump.

I prefer to get the dewiki geolocations